# Main window form showing up blank

Tags: c#, winforms

I've gone through a number of the other questions regarding this issue.

The form loads, but it's missing all its controls. It used to work. Clearly I screwed something up but I cannot figure out what I changed to break it.

I've checked and my UploaderUI.cs is spelled correctly. Its code is below:

```
namespace uploaderUI
{
    static class UploaderUI
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new mainForm());
        }
    }
}
```

My `InitializeComponent` is working, and I am able to set a break point and step through all of it.

```
public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create an instance of a ListView column sorter and assign
        // to the ListView control.
        lvwColumnSorter = new ListViewColumnSorter();
        this.listViewNotCurrent.ListViewItemSorter = lvwColumnSorter;
    }
```

I'm at a loss, I don't know what else to look for. Not even sure what else to post here that can help.

Comment: Do you have a older working version to compare it to, e.g. in source control?

Comment: working through that now.  I don't have formal source control yet. (regretting that every second I do this)

Comment: Can you dump the code of InitializeComponent(); Could a container control's visibility be set to false somehow? Or controls created but not added? What if you loop through this.Controls?

Comment: Im guessing you have an exception in your form load event, InitializeComponent or something called from one of them. Are you able to step through with the debugger?

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem. What I was doing was creating the form on a thread other than the "Main" form UI. This caused the "blank" form issue. Fix it by changing your code or ensuring the form creation happens on the UI thread:

```
mainForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
     new Form();
});
```

Comment: Where does this snippet go, i.e. which file and approximately where?

Comment: @mLstudent33 This is an example of how to force the Form class to be created on the UI thread (main form). Look for where you create your form that you are having problems with (in my case it's new Form()) and wrap the two lines around it. If it helps then you were having the same problem as me (the form was being created on a thread other than the main UI thread) otherwise it's something else.

Comment: I actually "fixed" it with a rebuild.  I have a Python background so sometimes I forget the most basic things.